# Team Foundation Build 2010 - Add project property file (.props) to all projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

I am building several VC++ projects using TFBuild 2010. I want all of them to inherit a .props file. Is there a way to do this in the build process? I know I can manually add the .props sheet to each using the property manager in Visual Studio, but would rather have a more elegant solution.

I am running the the build service under the NT AUTHORITY\Network Service account, so I don't think I can take advantage of the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props sheet in the user's AppData folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NT AUTHORITY\Network Service does in fact have an AppData folder in C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles. I edited the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props in this folder, which solved my problem.